# Trace of exception in message header on dead letter queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-cloud-stream to consume message from Rabbit MQ.
I have a queue and dead-letter-queue binding to it. Whenever there is any exception, messages are getting routed to dead-letter-queue.

My question is - **Can we put a header in message with Exception class before receiving it on dead letter queue. Or, how do we know which exception occurred by looking at the message.** 
I would like to repair, re queue or park the messages based on exception.

Comment: The Error Message has the original Message in it as well as the Exception information. Isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok, may be I am missing something. I have a @StreamListener on my DLQ.  I am receiving a GenericMessage rather than the Error message. Should I have a listener at erroChannel to get the ErrorMessage.

Comment: That is correct the global `errorChannel` and/or binding specific channel as described here - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_application_error_handling

Comment: To get exception information in the DLQ, you need to use `republishToDlq` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the rejected message when it is sent to the DLQ by RabbitMQ itself; for that reason the binder provides a consumer property `republishToDlq` where, instead of the rejecting the message and having RabbitMQ send it to the DLQ, the binder itself publishes it there, and adds headers with exception information etc.

Comment: thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I missed this property while reading the doc.